# Связка OpenCL + Delphi в научных расчётах: пример

Tags: delphi, opencl, delphi-xe8

Уже где-то пару лет пишу расчётный код (выч.гидродинамика) только под *OpenCL 1.2.* Даже [статью](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mm&paperid=3878&option_lang=rus) про это уже написал.

Сама интерфейсная часть - на *Delphi XE8*: для создания меню, прочего формошлёпства, общения с БД, вывода 2D и 3D графики - вполне удобно.

Сам *OpenCL* - фактически сводится к обычному программированию на *C99*: написанию *Kernel* в виде отдельных текстовых файлов.

Предпочёл *OpenCL*, а не *CUDA*, т.к. он работает и на **Nvidia**, и на **AMD**. К сожалению, полноценной поддержки OpenCL 2.0 пока у Nvidia нет (например, pipes не работают).

Итак. Давал в 2016 году работающий пример на разных форумах: можете погуглить на слова `OpenCL Delphi 64bit`.

**Кое-что там обновил впоследствии**: может будет полезно участникам форума...
Вот [ссылка](http://gofile.me/2Zesj/C0f3wb1o) для скачивания с моего NAS.

Там в папке:

1. Полезная утилита **GPU_Caps_Viewer_Setup_v1.32.0.0.exe** для
   контроля состояния видеокарты, особенно, если нажать кнопку "More
   GPU Info".
2. **OpenCL1_2_Delphi.zip** - файл с примером от чехов
   (Университет Брно, насколько помню) использования OpenCL в Delphi,
   2013год. У меня этот пример не всегда корректно работал при
   компиляции под Win64 (не на всех видео-картах). Но там хороший
   заголовочный файл CL.pas - его можно чуть доработать с учётом
   замечания про NativeInt с другого форума: заменить тип size_t на
   NativeInt для Win64, и использовать вместо моего "укороченного"
   OpenCLHeaders.pas - см.ниже.
3. *Вложенная папка с моим вариантом программы-теста*. Последняя версия в папке : **OpenCL_Demo2016 Fast Delphi XE8** Она самодостаточна: больше ничего не надо, ну разве что последние версии видео-драйверов установить. Тест сделан под Delphi XE8 (работает и под Berlin/Tokyo). Причём работает, по крайней мере у меня, при компиляции под Win32, и что более важно- под Win64. *Всего 2 файла*:

   - **OpenCLHeaders.pas**: заголовочный; я его урезал - убрал ненужные мне функции, которые в принципе можно взять из файла чехов CL.pas + учёл полезное замечание с др.форма про NativeInt;
   - **OpenCLSelect.pas** : тестовая программа. Выделяет на GPU память (создаёт буферы) под 16 массивов (квадратных матриц из cl_Float, размер стороны которых задаётся на основной форме, по умолчанию 1400) и под ещё один массив, того же размера, куда пишется результат несложных вычислений на GPU. Потом запускается итерационный цикл (StepMax -количество итераций - для проверки времени работы - задаётся тоже на форме, по умолчанию - 12). Внутри каждой итерации 16 массивов заполняются данными, затем запускается ещё и внутренний цикл: 30 проходов вызова расчётного ядра на GPU. Такая структура тестовой программы больше всего подходит под наши научные задачи    (вычислит. гидродинамика), но здесь это лишь тест. В тесте есть несложная проверка правильности вычислений на CPU - для одного из элементов матрицы-результата, поскольку **НЕ** все драйверы видеокарт (особенно старые) могут диагностировать Kernel Error. Результаты сопоставления (погрешность DELTA вычислений GPU vs CPU) выводятся на форме по окончании программы (обозначены CHost и CGPU, соответственно).
     Crit - это значение (критерий), кол-во выходов за который подсчитываются, например, atomic-функциями; по умолчанию 48: если уменьшить - выходов станет больше.
   - программа на С для ядра - текстовый файл **ProgramGPU1.cpp** (должен лежать рядом с *.exe !!): там можно глянуть, что делается с одномерными массивами на GPU. Она прямо передаётся в виде строки на GPU, там копилируется и линкуется - ну как обычно в OpenCL. Второй файл **ProgramGPU2.cpp** - просто чтобы убедиться, что из разных файлов можно Kernel подгружать: он тоже должен лежать рядом с *.exe при запуске. Нужная DLL для OpenCL - под Win64 или Win32 - подключится из системных папок Windows автоматически, в зависимости от компиляции.
4. Примеры более сложных Kernel (17штук) из реальной расчётной программы.

Можете потестить. Если будете вносить изменения в файлы на cpp и допустите ошибку, то драйвер видеокарты при компиляции её определит, и выскочит чёрное окно с описанием ошибки.

Теперь собственно вопрос: где (на какой ветке этого или другого форума) обсуждаются научные вычисления с применением *OpenCL*?

---

---

---

Дополню (конец декабря 2017). Внутри той же  [ссылки](http://gofile.me/2Zesj/C0f3wb1o) для скачивания добавил папку:

**OpenCL_Demo2017 Barrier and Local_Memory REDUCT**

---

В ней новый пример под **Delphi XE8 64bit** (работает и при компиляции в **Delphi** под **Win32**, но с ограничениями, о которых будет сказано ниже). Отличия:

1. Добавлен пример простейшей редукции с использованием *barrier* и *LocalMemory* с обилием комментариев внутри *Kernel*-файла **ProgramGPU1.cpp**
2. Показано, как внутри Kernel создать а-ля динамический массив
   (стандарт языка OpenCL 1.2 этого не позволяет).
3. **Главное.** На форме добавлены
       Gauge-компоненты, показывающие:

   - общую загрузку **CPU** ;
   - загрузку **CPU** данной задачей ;
   - загрузку **GPU** (общую);
   - загрузку контроллера памяти **GPU** ;
   - проценты использованной памяти **GPU** ;
   - температуру **GPU** (в текстовом виде).

---

Для определения загрузки **GPU** используется **nvml.dll** - [мануал 2017](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/NVML_API_Reference_Guide.pdf), так что последние **4** параметра определяются только для карт NVIDIA, и при компиляции в Delphi под **64bit**. Эта динамич. библиотека для каждой карты NVIDIA - своя, обычно при установке драйвера карты она попадает в папку 
    **C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvml.dll** (этот путь прямо прописан в прилагаемом примере по  ссылке).

Всё что связано с определением загрузки **CPU-GPU** находится в отдельном модуле **ProcessorUsage.pas**, который может быть применён и для других программ (без **OpenCL**).

4. Если есть желание попробовать OpenCL не только на видеокартах, но и на процессорах **INTEL**, надо поставить [драйвер](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_CPU_runtime)

---

*Буду весьма признателен*, если кто-то подскажет способ измерения загрузки **GPU** от **AMD**, и самое простое - его температуры. Есть похожая *DLL*? 
Может, эти: **atiadlxx.dll  ,  atiadlxy.dll  ,  GPUPerfAPIGL.dll**  ?

---

***Всех с наступающим Новым годом!!***

---

Обновлённая ссылка на DEMO:
http://gofile.me/2Zesj/fbsharing-C0f3wb1o
  Последняя версия в папке:
OpenCL_Demo2018 Barrier and Local_Memory REDUCT Delphi Tokyo 10.2.2 !! LAST !!

Comment: День добрый и с наступающим! Вы пользуетесь Stack Overflow не по назначению, вот и вышло, что в течение двух месяцев ваш вопрос вряд ли кто-то прочитал целиком. (1) Здесь не форум и нет веток. Здесь задают изолированные вопросы без лишних подробностей, но при этом самостоятельные (никакого кода по ссылкам, части вопроса должны быть в самом вопросе). (2) Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном.

Comment: С определением текущей загрузки GPU типа AMD и его температуры уже разобрался (использовал функции из atiadlxx.dll). Не могу пока определить только процент использования памяти для AMD. К сожалению, не нашёл в Инете подробного мануала по atiadlxx.dll , atiadlxy.dll , GPUPerfAPIGL.dll

Comment: Ну, раз разобрались сами, вставлять свой ответ насчёт температуры и загрузки не буду. Касательно размера памяти - увы, документации не встречал. Возможно, за это отвечает одна из функций:  int ADL2_Adapter_MemoryInfo_Get (ADL_CONTEXT_HANDLE context, int iAdapterIndex, ADLMemoryInfo *lpMemoryInfo) или int ADL_Adapter_MemoryInfo_Get (int iAdapterIndex, ADLMemoryInfo *lpMemoryInfo)

Comment: Эти функции нормально работают, но они выдают только ОБЩЕЕ количество памяти на борту карты AMD, её тип (напр.GDDR5), скорость шины памяти. Но не сколько памяти уже занято! Пробовал ADL2_Adapter_MemoryInfo_Get