# Как использовать код из OpenCL в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, opencl

Как подключить свой код на OpenCL в Delphi? Как передаются данные туда и данные забираются результаты? Очень приветствуются примеры кода или хотя бы ссылки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738281/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-opencl-delphi-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

Answer (score 0):

Добавляю только ссылки на чужие страницы. (Сам, к сожалению, так и не добрался до этой темы).

- https://delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=30492
- https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=26:43673 (то же самое)
- https://mega.nz/file/wJtSzJJK#Ibp40J9hx1IrE6NrFbu5iIpnv4yd3GZKWOZx46ix12k (исходный код демо-проекта)